# How to change "Appendix A" to "Appendix"

Tags: lyx, koma-script, appendices

I'm using Lyx, Book(Koma-Script) document class. Everything seems to work OK except I've been fiddling around for ages trying to change the name of my single appendix in the TOC from "Appendix A. Blah blah" to "Appendix. Blah blah". I also want the appendix title in the body of the document to read "Appendix. Blah blah" rather than "A. Blah blah". I've inserted the following TEX code at the beginning of the appendix

```
\begin{appendices}

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}

\chapter{Planetary motion data}
```

with `\end{appendices}` at the end of the appendix. In Document Settings/Latex Preamble I've put `\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}`. My knowledge of coding etc is zero. I've just used trial and error to copy/paste fragments of code I've found online to get where I am now. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would exploit the fact that chapters after `\backmatter` are not numbered:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{A title}

% <body of document>

\backmatter

\chapter{Appendix. Planetary motion data}

% <text of appendix>

\end{document}
```

Comment: With a bit of fiddling that appears to work. I deleted all my code, added \backmatter followed by \addchap{Appendix. Planetary motion data}. I used \addchap instead of \chapter because the latter numbers the appendix, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want nothing more, than what you have described, than you can simply use an unnumbered chapter with `\chapter*` or the `\frontmatter`-`\mainmatter`-`\backmatter` commands from `scrbook` or you can redefine the chapter numbering:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}
% \renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{Appendix.}
\chapter{Planetary motion data}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

I don't know nothing about LyX in detail, so I made up this MWE from the other information you gave.

I also don't know nothing of the `appendix` package, but the name suggests some functionality that is already provided by `scrbook`. So maybe you should check [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) for more information on how to exploit your document class.