# How do I change 'A' to 'Appendix A' in both TOC and title?

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, appendices

I wanna display `A` as `Appendix A` in TOC, as shown below.

[image]

I tried to add `\backmatter` before `\appendix` as shown in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103954/how-to-change-appendix-a-to-appendix), but `cref{label}` will display as `Section 1`. I also used `\renewcommand` as suggested in the most posts on this site, but it doesn't make any changes. Here is the source code.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc, title]{appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixname{Anexo}
%\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anexos}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{The main body of the text}
Refer to \cref{appendix} for more information.

\appendix
\section{A complete table.} \label{appendix}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure your readers need that extra word to know the appendix just started? You don't have the word *Chapter* for all the chapters, right? It is an article document, you don't have *Section* in front of every section entry, right?

Comment: If you want to show "Appendix A" instead of just "A" in the ToC, do you want to show the longer string in the actual section-level header as well?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I just wanna show `Appendix A` in my TOC and left the tile blank, like `\section{}`.

Comment: @Mico An idea comes to my mind. I remove `A` and put `Appendix A` into `\section{}`.

Comment: `\appendix\section*{Appendix}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}` But that isn't a very good thing to do.

Comment: If there is just one section, i wouldn't even bother calling it an appendix. `\section*{Additional material}`

Comment: @Johannes_B, I tried `\section*{}`, but the cross reference `\cref{label}` displays as `Section 1` instead of `Appendix A`.

Comment: @Johannes_B, it doesn't work for the cross references which will be displayed as `Section 1` instead of `Appendix A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\newcommand{\appendixnumberline}[1]{Appendix\space}

\let\oldappendix\appendix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\numberline\protect\appendixnumberline}%
  \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Appendix~\csname the##1\endcsname\quad}%
  \oldappendix
}
\makeatother
```

The above replaces the `\numberline` macro with a new `\appendixnumberline` while also updating the way sectional unit counter are formatted when setting the section title. All is included at the start of the `\appendix` as a form of automation.

[image]

If you also use `\subsection` (and lower) within the appendix, some more work needs to be done to exclude their sectional units from also being prepended with `Appendix`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you take a different approach: Instead of overloading any given line in the table of contents, consider inserting a line saying something like "Appendix material" in the ToC right before the first appendix section.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % make \cref look like \autoref

%% Set up some preparatory code -- activated below
%% (see 'The LaTeX Companion,' 2nd. ed., pp. 26f.)
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%   default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% enable individual control
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\bigskip\hrule % just for this example

\section{Uno}
Refer to \Cref{app:a,app:b} for more information.
\section{Due}
More text.
\section{Tre}
Still more text.

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip\medskip\noindent%
  \textbf{Appendix Material}\par}
% Activate preparatory code for section-level headers
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\section@cntformat}{Appendix \thesection\quad}
\makeatother

\section{A complete table.} \label{app:a}
Some text.

\section{Another complete table.} \label{app:b}
Other text.

\end{document}
```